# Is "didn't have a X to do with" a common/idiomatic phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

Google only returns [6](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22have%20a%20*%20to%20do%20with%22&*) results. So I'm a bit skeptic.

Example sentence:

> I didn't want to eat the food, though **it didn't have a pinch to do**
>   with the taste.

Is the phrase common/idiomatic? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: It is not common at all, but a bit of a play on words, compare "a pinch of salt".  "a thing to do with" is the normal phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula:

> didn't have a *X* to do with

I hear quite a bit. The X is often "thing" and frequently an intensifier is included:

> That didn't have a () *thing* to do with it.

where () is the intensifier.
To me, this construction is so common, it cannot be referred to as unusual.
[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=damn%20thing%20to%20do%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdamn%20thing%20to%20do%20with%3B%2Cc0) only allows five words but "damn thing to do with" was well represented.
If you wanted to use the formula:

> didn't have a *X* to do with

I would think using *thing* for *X* would be fine, and acceptable in all but the most formal writing.

> a thing to do with

is also well represented in [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20thing%20to%20do%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20thing%20to%20do%20with%3B%2Cc0)